# Nested Array Insertion Failing in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and exploring Mongo DB for my learning purpose.So for expert people my question may looks to be too basic but if any one could clear my doubts that would helpful for me.

I am trying to insert one record in mongo DB from command line shell.Below is the query for the same:

```
db.my_data.insert({
    "state_name":"State1",
    "building_usage_data": [{
        "area_type":"Urban",
        "building_usage": [
            {"usage_type":"House","total":1663832},
            {"usage_type":"Shop","total":352312 },
            {"usage_type":"Hotel","total":5582 },
            {"usage_type":"Hospital","total":5752},
            {"usage_type":"Temple","total":8442},
            {"usage_type":"Factory","total":3842},
            {"usage_type":"Shopping Mall","total":742},
            {"usage_type":"Cinema Hall","total":642}
        ]
    },
    {
        "area_type":"Rural,
        "building_usage": [
            {"usage_type":"House","total":1963832},
            {"usage_type":"Shop","total":302312},
            {"usage_type":"Hospital","total":2752},
            {"usage_type":"Temple","total":9442},
            {"usage_type":"Factory","total":4842},
            {"usage_type":"Resort","total":842}
        ]
    }]
});
```

But above is failing with syntax error.It looks to me it is failing while inserting second element in array against `building_usage_data`. I am not able to understand what is the reason behind this failure.

As a alternate solution I have changed the query as per below which is running fine:

```
db.my_data.insert({
    "state_name":"State1",
    "Urban": [
        {"usage_type":"House","total":1663832},
        {"usage_type":"Shop","total":352312 },
        {"usage_type":"Hotel","total":5582 },
        {"usage_type":"Hospital","total":5752},
        {"usage_type":"Temple","total":8442},
        {"usage_type":"Factory","total":3842},
        {"usage_type":"Shopping Mall","total":742},
        {"usage_type":"Cinema Hall","total":642}
    ],
    "Rural": [
        {"usage_type":"House","total":1963832},
        {"usage_type":"Shop","total":302312},
        {"usage_type":"Hospital","total":2752},
        {"usage_type":"Temple","total":9442},
        {"usage_type":"Factory","total":4842},
        {"usage_type":"Resort","total":842}
    ]
});
```

If somebody could explain me why my first insert query is failing that would be helpful.

Comment: You've got a stray [ on the rural temple line

Comment: @FrederickCheung thanks for pointing out.It looks like while copying the query here I have put in extra [ on rural temple line.Query is not working after removing extra [.

Comment: The issue is with this section: `"area_type": "Rural,"building_usage":[` - The quotation marks do not match and the key already has a value so you can not specify a textual and array value for that key.

Comment: I recommend using a [JSON validation tool](http://jsonlint.com/) so that you can arrive at these conclusions much faster than attempting to validate JSON structures with only visual aids.

Comment: JSON has error, you can check it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Lix thanks for recommending JSON validation tool and pin pointing to exact issue.Issue was as you rightly said quotation mark for   '"area_type": "Rural,' was not matching.I am able to run the query now.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @VijayendraBhati - glad to help! JSON formatting and validation tools were super useful for me when I worked with mongo. Happy coding!